# How to add a dimension in numpy array? (125, 125) to (125, 125, 1)

Tags: python, numpy

I am loading an image using OpenCV python as a greyscale image because of which the shape of the image is `(125, 125)`. But, I need the shape to be `(125, 125, 1)` where 1 denotes the number of channels ( 1 since it's greyscale ).

```
img = cv2.imread('/path/to/image.png', 0)
print(img.shape)
# prints (125, 125)
```

Now, I need to convert `img`'s shape to `(125, 125, 1)`

Comment: `img.reshape(125,125,-1)` would d it for you if the dimensions remain constant, otherwise use `np.expand_dims`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`numpy` indexing and `np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

```
img = np.ones((125, 125)) # img.shape: (125, 125)
img_3d = img[..., np.newaxis] # img_3d.shape: (125, 125, 1)
```

This is especially handy if you only need the extra dimensions to pass the data to another function, so you can just pass the fancy-indexed array.

Answer (score 4):

Try `np.expand_dims`:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: img = np.ones((125, 125))

In [3]: img.shape
Out[3]: (125, 125)

In [4]: img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=-1)

In [5]: img.shape
Out[5]: (125, 125, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(5,5)
b = a.reshape(5,5,1) 
b = a.reshape(1,5,5)
b = a.reshape(1,5,5,1)
```

any shape you want